# How to properly document text/csv responses on swagger/yaml docs?

Tags: csv, yaml, swagger, openapi

I have a bunch of API endpoints that return `text/csv` content in their responses. How do I document this? Here is what I currently have:

```
  /my_endpoint:
    get:
      description: Returns CSV content
      parameters:
        - $ref: '#/components/parameters/myParemeters'
      responses:
        200:
          headers:
            $ref: '#/components/headers/myHeaders'
          content: text/csv
```

As it stands, this does not work and I get the note in the Swagger preview:

> Could not render this component, see the console.

The question is how do I properly display the content for csv responses? I find if does work if I do add a schema, something like this:

```
...
  content:
      text/csv:
        schema:
          type: array
          items:
            type: string
...
```

But there shouldn't be a schema since it is csv. So to go back to the question, what is the proper way to describe the csv response content?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your first example is not valid syntax. Replace with:

```yaml
      responses:
        '200':
          content:
            text/csv: {}  # <-----

          # Also note the correct syntax for referencing response headers:
          headers:
            Http-Header-Name:  # e.g. X-RateLimit-Remaining
              $ref: '#/components/headers/myHeader'

components:
  headers:
    myHeader:
      description: Description of this response header
      schema:
        type: string
```

As for your second example, OpenAPI Specification does not provide examples of CSV responses. So the `schema` could be `type: string`, or an array of strings, or an empty schema `{}` (this means "any value"), or something else. The actual supported syntax might be tool-dependent. Feel free to ask for clarifications in the [OpenAPI Specification repository](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues).

Answer (score 6):

Here is another worked one for openapi 3.0.2 to return text/csv content (string) from backend:

OpenAPI yaml.spec:

```
    get:
      responses:
        200:
          description: Success. It returns CSV format.
          content:
            text/csv:
              schema:
                type: string
```

Backend:

```
HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
httpHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("text/csv"));
httpHeaders.setContentDispositionFormData("attachment", "sample.csv");

ResponseEntity.ok()
     .headers(httpHeaders)
     .body("h1,h2,h3,h4\n1,2,3,4\n5,6,7,8");
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one more example:

Contract:

```
  responses:
    '200':
      schema:
        type: object
```

Backend:

```
return ResponseEntity.status(200).contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("text/csv")).body("Col 1;Col2\naaa;bbb\nccc;ddd");
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Try this -- It should let you document an example as csv not json.

```
  responses:
    '200':
      description: 'Some data in csv format'
      content:
        text/csv:
          schema:
            type: string
          example: |-
            name, country, column etc
            Alice, UK, blah
            Bob, France, whatever
```